# create a speedrun timer in Unity / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a timer that counts up. This timer has to be very precisely because it represents the current level timer for speedrunners.

I tested some ways..

using **Time.deltaTime**

```
float currentTime = 0;

private void Update()
{
    currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

using **Time.timeSinceLevelLoad**

```
    float startTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float currentTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad - startTime;
    }
```

using **DateTime.Now**

```
DateTime startTime;

private void Start()
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void Update()
{
    TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
}
```

using **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch**

```
private Stopwatch watch;

private void Start()
{
    watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
}

private void Update()
{
    TimeSpan currentTime = watch.Elapsed;
}
```

Which one might be the best?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` has imprecision of ~10ms. `timeSinceLevelLoad` tells you time in seconds which for your needs is useless.

Comment: Beware that Unity timer loses precision on long sessions (~8 hours onwards).

Comment: I added one more way, seems the `Stopwatch` might be the best?

Comment: This is about precision? `Time.deltaTime` is and should be the most with  best precision. Unfortunately, I can't prove this so it's not worth adding as an answer but I've seen similar question on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) which proved that `Time.deltaTime` is more precise. Can't find it anymore

Comment: hm okay, I don't know sorry

Comment: Found it. Read the answers from [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141807/what-happens-when-time-time-gets-very-large-in-unity) post. `Time.deltaTime` is more precise than subtracting two time stamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last solution appears to be the best, but I would move `currentTime` to a class property so that you could access it elsewhere.

```
DateTime startTime;
public TimeSpan timeElapsed { get; private set; }

private void Start()
{

    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void Update()
{
    this.timeElapsed= DateTime.Now - startTime;
}
```

Or you could use the [StopWatch](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) class. This gives you a few options to choose from as your output. Like such:

```
private StopWatch stopwatch;
public TimeSpan timeElapsed { get; private set; }

private void Start()
{
    stopwatch = new StopWatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
}

private void Update()
{
    timeElapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: sorry I just added the `Stopwatch` to my question some seconds ago :P but thanks